# Window Resize JS turn function on and off

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have function that I need to turn off in a media query because it runs super slow on mobile devices. The function doesnt fire when it is loaded on the particular window size but does when resized to that particular size below 1024px my assumption is my headerParallax = null isnt doing anything and I need it to remove the function on window resize for mobile sizes another way.

I have tried just passing in null values into the function like `headerParallax(null)`, however  the function still seems to be running, like the $(window).scroll seems to be still attached so the mobile devices even though no animation is happening still are not very responsive on scroll.

Thanks

```
var headerParallax = function (x, z, y) {



  $(window).scroll(function() {
    // Store scrollTop in variable
    var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
    // var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
    //console.log(scrollPos + 'bgbottle1');

    var bouncePos = ((-1 * (scrollPos ) * 1.30) + scrollPos).toFixed(2);

    var bouncePos1 = ((-1 * (scrollPos -100) * 1.40) + scrollPos).toFixed(2);

    var bouncePos2 = ((-1 * (scrollPos -150) * 1.265) + scrollPos).toFixed(2);


    $(".bottle1").css({ 'background-position': x + bouncePos + 'px'});



    console.log( x + "," + bouncePos + "," + scrollPos);

    //if (scrollPos > 50){

      $(".bottle2").css({ 'background-position': z + bouncePos1 + 'px'});



  //  }

    //if (scrollPos > 850){

      $(".glass").css({ 'background-position': y + bouncePos2 + 'px'});

    //}

  });
} // end headerParallax


//Window resizing fucnsions

$(window).resize(function(){
    if($(window).width() > 1024 ){


    //These variables allow the glass to hold its background position on a window.resize.
    var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
    var bouncePos2 = ((-1 * (scrollPos -215.75) * 1.25) + scrollPos).toFixed(2);


    $(".bottle1").css({ 'background-position': "368px 0"});
    $(".bottle2").css({ 'background-position': "73px 125px"});
    $(".glass").css({ 'background-position': "750px " + bouncePos2 + "px"});
    //window.requestAnimationFrame(headerParallax("368px ","-452px ", "900px "));
    headerParallax("368px ","73px ", "750px ");

    alert("on1");


  }else if($(window).width() > 920 && $(window).width() < 1024){
    //These variables allow the glass to hold its background position on a window.resize.
    var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
    var bouncePos2 = ((-1 * (scrollPos -215.75) * 1.25) + scrollPos).toFixed(2);
    $(".bottle1").css({ 'background-position': "368px 0"});
    $(".bottle2").css({ 'background-position': "73px 125px"});
    $(".glass").css({ 'background-position': "750px " + bouncePos2 + "px"});

    headerParallax = null;


    alert("off1")

    //headerParallax(null);

  }else if($(window).width() < 920){
    var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
    var bouncePos2 = ((-1 * (scrollPos -215.75) * 1.25) + scrollPos).toFixed(2);
    $(".bottle1").css({ 'background-position': "150px 0"});
    $(".bottle2").css({ 'background-position': "-400px 125px"});
    $(".glass").css({ 'background-position': "470px "  + bouncePos2 + "px"});
    //window.requestAnimationFrame(headerParallax("150px ","-500px ", "600px "));
    headerParallax = null;

    alert("off2");

  }
}); //end windoResize

if($(window).width() > 1024 ){
  //window.requestAnimationFrame(headerParallax("368px ", "-452px ", "900px "));
  headerParallax("368px ","73px ", "750px ");

}else if($(window).width() > 920 && $(window).width() < 1024){

  headerParallax = null;


}else if($(window).width() < 920 ){
  //window.requestAnimationFrame(headerParallax("150px ","-500px ", "600px "));
  headerParallax = null;


}
```

Comment: you need to debound scroll and resize, especially on mobile. the event can fire dozens of times a second, but since your animation takes longer than 1/50th of a second, you are stacking up animations and killing the CPU. delay and re-schedule the animation to  happen 100ms after the last scroll/resize

Comment: Could you give me a hand possibly on how to do so.

Comment: I dont want it to run on mobile at all though.